# Pull all of the text from a simple HTML page

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I want to pull all the text from this page: https://pastebin.com/raw/HtqbjSdE

I already have:

```
response = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/HtqbjSdE")
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(str(response.content)), parser)
contentPath = "//body//pre/text()"
pasteContent = tree.xpath(contentPath)
```

However `tree.xpath(contentPath)` just returns an empty array.

I've also tried several variations of the contentPath

What am I doing wrong?